# circuitikz: Adjust label in switch and transformator

Tags: circuitikz

In a circuit I am putting together in circuitikz I want to use a switch and a transformator. However I am not able to put the label of the switch on the left side. And the label of the transformator is too low. How can I put the transformator label higher or make the trafo wider?

Here is the code and a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}


    \draw (4,-1) node[nigfete,anchor=D,bodydiode] {$S_1$};

    \draw (9,-3.75) node [transformer core](T){}  
      (T.A1) node[above] {}
      (T.A2) node[below] {}
      (T.B1) node[above] {} 
      (T.B2) node[below] {}
      (T.base) node{$n_1:n_2$};

    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is rude solution, but it may works what you after:

- case: 1

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[
lbl/.style = {label={[label distance=6mm]left:#1}}
                    ]
\draw (4,-1) node[nigfete,bodydiode, anchor=D, lbl=$S_1$] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

- case: 2

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (9,-3.75) node [transformer core] (T) {$n_1:n_2$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

- case 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (9,-3.75) node [transformer core] (T) {}
        (T.base) node[above, color=red] {$n_1:n_2$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```